# How do I extract client data from the httpheaders?

Tags: spring, http-headers

I have a login post request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = EWPRestContants.DO_LOGIN, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> doLogin(@RequestBody Loginrequest logReq,@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws Exception {
   //........
     }
```

I want to extract data from the header. Is there an API to do so?

Suppose my header contains customer msIsdn number and name. How do I fetch those details. getFirst() is used to get the user-agent details or the start line only.

This is the answer.
`String id= headers.getFirst("ID");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like

@RequestHeader(value="User-Agent", defaultValue="foo") String userAgent

```
@RequestMapping(value = EWPRestContants.DO_LOGIN, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> doLogin(@RequestBody Loginrequest logReq,@RequestHeader(value="User-Agent", defaultValue="foo") String userAgent,@RequestHeader(value="Accept-Language") String acceptLanguage, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws Exception {
   //........
     }
```

or from

```
    @RequestMapping(value = EWPRestContants.DO_LOGIN, method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,produces=MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> doLogin(@RequestBody Loginrequest logReq,@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws Exception {
String userAgent = headers.getFirst(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT);
         }
```

Comment: From the second solution  `USER_AGENT cannot be resolved or is not a field` I get the following error.

Comment: Thank you @kuhajeyan for your effort.